# How to display list tag inline when there's divs and images inside?

Tags: html, css

```css
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
       <p>This is some text in list 1 and is in a div tag</p>
    </div>
  </li>
   
  <li class="li_2">
    <div>
       <p>This is some text in list 2 class and is in a div tag</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I make it so that the list is displayed inline? It doesn't, I think, because the list items contain `div` tags, but I'm not sure. I want each item in the list to be next to each other.

Comment: you have to also make the div and p inline

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to happen, but if you want to create list items that form rectangle-shaped elements which are next to to each other horizontally, use `display: inline-block;` and define a `width` for them. The `div`s and `p` elements inside them will have full width by default, i.e. the width you define for the inline-blocks:

```css
ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
       <p>This is some text in list item 1 and is in a div tag</p>
    </div>
  </li>
   
  <li class="li_2">
    <div>
       <p>This is some text in list item 2 and is in a div tag</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
       <p>This is some text in list item 3 and is in a div tag</p>
    </div>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

If you really want *everything* to be inline (including the contents of the list items, i.e. the `div`s and `p` tags), you need to apply `display: inline` to all of them (But I can't imagine a situation where that would be practical...):

```css
li, div, p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
       <p>This is some text in list item 1 and is in a div tag</p>
    </div>
  </li>
   
  <li class="li_2">
    <div>
       <p>This is some text in list item 2 and is in a div tag</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
       <p>This is some text in list item 3 and is in a div tag</p>
    </div>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

With flexbox css it's easy

```css
ul{
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      <div>
         <p>This is some text in list 1 and is in a div tag</p>
      </div>
    </li>
     
    <li>
      <div>
         <p>This is some text in list 2 class and is in a div tag</p>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Base on your question, it seems you want the items to be in one line but before I can give a solution I need to explain what is going on.

When an element i.e. `DIV` is a child of another element i.e. `LI` it scope is within that parent element, therefore any styling applied on it will be scoped in that parent, and will only affect that element with that parent and nothing more, except you're using a selector to affect changes in style to all children, siblings and more. For example, by default every `DIV` element have their `display` CSS properties set to `block` for example, see the code below

```
{
  display: 'block'
}
```

So now in your case you have a list element, inside an unordered list element, every `LI` you create will have a default padding, and a display of `block` so to ensure they all fall in the same line or be inline as stated in your question, you will need to change the display property to `inline` or `inline-flex`, you can only use `inline-flex` mostly if you want it to have the property of a flex box and still remain inline to the parent element.

So to achieve what you want to do, I advice you remove the padding, either set it to 0 for now, then set the display property to 'inline' and then add the padding again to give each element enough spacing as you want until you get your desire look or design. For any question, just comment here.